# show ads in flutter website(flutter web app)

Tags: flutter, admob, ads, adsense, flutter-web

How to implement AdSense or any other to show ads on the flutter website (flutter web app).

Which are the ad provider options like Adsense for a flutter web app.

Answer (score 1):

Currently if you try, your application will be submitted for review, and then you will inaccurately obtain a  "Valuable Inventory: No content" flag/violation. The problem is noticed though, but unfortunately it will be a good amount of time before it gets prioritized over the mobile ad framework.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40376

Answer (score 0):

I don't think flutter is in a mood to encourage adds on flutter web. Google uses crawlers to search the content on websites which will not work in case of flutter that well event though you try to inject adds through js code using plugin and this made me scrape my whole UI project and start it over again on angular or react.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this new package I just saw has been released. Still in the infancy stages as it says but it's a start at least.

https://pub.dev/packages/admanager_web

Example of implementation:

```
 AdBlock(
     size: AdBlockSize.largeRectangle,
     adUnitId: "/6355419/Travel/Europe", 
 )
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33110997)